# InputMask для Android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, inputmask

Использую плагин InputMask и столкнулся с такой проблемой: пользователи жалуются, что на некоторых устройствах (телефоны на Android OS) не вводится номер телефона или не удаляются цифры.

Я использую этот плагин вот так:

```
$('input[type="tel"]').inputmask('+7 (999) 999-99-99', {
    autoUnmask: true,
    showMaskOnHover: false,
    removeMaskOnSubmit:true
});
```

В каких-то случаях появляется маска +7 (777) 777-77-77. Я не знаю откуда берутся эти семерки, могу лишь только предположить, что где-то что-то не так копируется и парсится, но где именно - не знаю. Если кто-то сталкивался с подобной проблемой, помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: react native или как вы JS в андроид используете?

Comment: @pavlofff на сайте. Просто на сайте использую вот этот плагин https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask